# Redirecting to callback page during twitter authentication

Tags: android, callback, twitter, twitter4j

I follow tutorial from http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/comment-page-2/#comment-10881. I also fix the bugs following comments. But during authentication after i allow application I am redirected to page from callback which shouldn't happens in mobile app. This are screenshots:

http://imageshack.us/f/41/device20111201155433.png

http://imageshack.us/f/638/device20111201133338.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Link for Twitter integration with Android Application :

[Twitter Integration with Android](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application)

Just download this tutorial and Open File named **Constants.java** and put the **Consumer Key and Secret Key.**

Also follow the Steps given to create application.

Give some **Dummy call Back Url**.. Then only it will **Redirect to your Application**.